# Mysql Select Where id<100

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to this query in php:

```
$sql= "SELECT pcampo6 FROM productos WHERE id >= 100";
```

This is the error i get:

```
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 100' at line 1
```

I also tried :

```
$sql = "SELECT `pcampo6` FROM productos WHERE eliminado=0 AND `id` >= 101";
$sql = "SELECT 'pcampo6' FROM productos WHERE eliminado=0 AND 'id' >= 101";
$sql = "SELECT pcampo6 FROM productos WHERE eliminado=0 AND id >= '101'";
```

Comment: Your queries seem right to me. Are you sure you are copying them verbatim? Do you have some hidden symbols between `>` and `=`?

Comment: I think you need the single quotes around the 100 not the id

Comment: How are you executing the query?

Comment: @AMR: those are backticks, not single quotes

Comment: @AMR why should OP surround a number with single quotes?

Comment: the type of the colum id is?

Comment: The query was being encoded, so the > symbols where converted into another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is *nothing* wrong with the query you posted.

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4aacb/1)

- If your `id` column is not an integer type, try using single quotes around the value

The error is probably coming from elsewhere in code that you are not showing us.

Comment: id its an Integer type, the werid thing is that it works fine if i do:
$sql= "SELECT pcampo6 FROM productos WHERE id = 100";

Comment: Take your schema and some sample data and test it in SQL Fiddle.